# Trying to reflect a method which accepts a generic type

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I have a method add which adds a generic object (i.e. T) into an List. I want to unit test this method.

```
public static <T> List<T> add(List<T> list, T t) {
    if(list == null) return null;
    if(t == null) return list;

    List<T> outputList = new ArrayList<T>(list);
    outputList.add(t); // append item into list

    return outputList;
}
```

I am trying to get the Method and test it. I have written following code snippet to obtain the method (which i know is not correct).

```
Class myClass = Myclass.class;
Class<List<T>> clazz = (Class<List<T>>) Class.forName("java.util.ArrayList");
Method myObjectMethod = myClass.getMethod("add", ...) // i need to identify T's class
```

Certain trail-error attempts lead me to NoSuchMethod exceptions.

Can anybody help me in identifying this method? any pointers to rectify the above code?

Thanks!

Comment: Just out of interest, why do you need reflection to test this method?

Comment: I am exposing this method in custom Eclipse. As you might be aware, Eclipse uses reflection (introspect the classes and suggest methods).. So, before adding it into Eclipse, i just wanted to unit test..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`clazz` should probably be `List.class`, not `ArrayList.class`.  You have to use the exact raw type used in the method definition.

Comment: Can you explain how can i handle a generic List ie.e List<T>? Also, how can i pass the Class for the second parameter i.e. T to get the Method in this class.

Comment: Due to type erasure, generics aren't there as far as reflection is concerned.  You need to pass `myClass.getMethod("add", List.class, Object.class)` to get the method you've described.